# How to get my GPU to work with my display?

Tags: graphics-card, display, power, gpu

I get no BIOS on the screen, just a black display.

The screen was working with my desktop on integrated graphics for about 4 months, running Ubuntu, before I added my GPU.

The screen is an Acer, Model TCO03, with a VGA port and it's own power supply.

The GPU is a single slot INNO 3D GeForce GTX 1050Ti 4GB (DDR5).

It says it requires 400W and I have a 600W power supply, and from what I read, other components really don't draw all that much? The other components are motherboard, fan, 2x8GB RAM, and a Kaby Lake i7 4-core processor.

The GPU has no obvious additional power connectors and the output is DIV-D where my display is VGA, so I'm using a DVI-D to VGA converter.

The desktop is lighting up and making all the right noises so it's not a power problem. Maybe its a hardware issue related to the GPU power supply and a single monitor.

What should I try to diagnose this issue?

Comment: You may want to remove it first, then go in your bios and put the priority to your PCI first or even disable the integrated graphics if you can. That should resolve your issue. On top of that you could try with another gpu just in case that one is defective.

btw, I know that some converters may be troublesome I highly suggest changing your cable so you don't have to use a converter just to be safe.

Comment: Its an old screen i'm using unfortunately it only has a VGA input and the GPU only has a DVI-D output.

Comment: Are you using BIOS or UEFI/CSM boot? You could test by switching it to the one you aren't using to see if you can see the BIOS on the screen at that point. If it works, you may need to look into if a BIOS update is available for your motherboard.